# Visual Studio, Gulp, Angular2 Final typescript error "cannot find name" and "Duplicate identifier"

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, npm, gulp

I have updated my project to use the angular 2 final release.  I also updaed visual studio to use typescript 2.0.3 from the Tool -> Extensions and Updates manager.

I use gulp to compile my typescript and it complies without error.  However I am getting thousands of errors inside visual studio.  The three most common errors are:

> Error TS2403 Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'httpVersionMinor' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'number'. **index.d.ts**
>
> Error TS2300  Duplicate identifier 'export='. **index.d.ts**
>
> Error TS2320  Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types
> 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.   Named property 'emit' of types
> 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.    **index.d.ts**

here is my tsconfig.json file:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true
      },
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings"
      ]
    }
```

Here is my typings.json file:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

here is my main.ts file:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

// APP imports *****************************************************
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

// ENABLE PRODUCTION MODE
    // enableProdMode();

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
```

### Problem:

If i remove this line:

> reference path="../typings/index.d.ts"

from the top of my main.ts file then the errors go away in visual studio, but then the errors all appear when I try to compile with gulp/npm.

### I have tried:

- using npm to uninstall and reinstall typings
- remove the typings and node modules folder and running *npm install*
- updating the visual studio version of typescript to 2.0.3
- making sure there are no references to es6 shim from earlier RC's

### Question

Can someone help me figure out why these errors are only thrown in Visual Studio when I reference the index.d.ts file or why the errors only appear in npm when I remove that reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

I switched my project to angular2 final and typescript 2.0.3

This caused problems as I develop in Visual Studio but use gulp tasks to compile and build my project.

So what I had to do to fix the error was:

- Update gulp-typescript, typings, tslint, coedlyzer, gulp-tslint to most recent version in my packages.json file
- Remove the index.d.ts reference from my main.ts file
- Update my gulp typescript compile task to included the index.d.ts file () shown below

Here is my new gulp task including my index.d.ts file:

```
gulp.task('ts:compile', function () {
return gulp
    .src(['./src/**/*.ts', 'typings/index.d.ts'], { base: '.' }) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(tsc(tsConfig.compilerOptions)) 
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.')); 

 });
```

Now visual studio does not throw errors and gulp compiles the code properly.

Sheesh.  The integration between visual studio and angular2 is still a bit rough